# How can i get form data from django layouts (like 'base.html') without sending forms in all page through views?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

many templates extend from base.html. base.html have one newsletter form that get email from user.  Is there any easy way to get the form data from 'base.html' to view.
(Sending forms in all page through views is possible But I think there is A easy good Looking idea)

Comment: use context processor OR use jquery to fetch the data and put within the form and send to django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a context processor to do so:

Add a new `.py` file in your root project, name it `context_processors.py`.

*context_processors.py*

```
from app.forms import GlobalForm

def global_variables(request):
   form = GlobalForm()
   context = {'global_form':form}
   return context
```

Then in settings.TEMPLATES add the context processors as the last line.

```
# stuff
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
'project_name.context_processors.global_variables'
```

So, `{{global_form}}` is available in all templates

Comment: What is the form action want to use?

Comment: Each view will have to handle the request, for instance, if you are in the homepage, you must retrieve the data from that view. and the form action can remain empty `form action=''` to indicate the current url/view

Comment: form action='' is loading empty page